# Assertion error while computing 2D convolution of the 2D input image

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, convolution

I am having assertion error while computing 2D convolution of an 2d image. I am struggling to assign correct range of `i` and `j` and then computing `Yield` keyword for view. It's giving me assertion error. Can somebody tell me what mistake I am committing and what should I evaluate 2D convolution while using `Yield` keyword? what should be the correct range of `i` and `j`?

```
import numpy as np


def convolve_2d(image, kernel_size=(3, 3)):
    """ yields (view, i, j) of a 2D convolution of
            the 2D input image

    """
    h, w = image.shape[0:2]  # it should work for gray input images, as well as for colored
    for i in range(0, 2):  
        for j in range(0, 2):  
            # view is the current "kernel" wide view of the image in the convolution
            view = image.copy()  

            yield view, i, j


res = list(convolve_2d(
    np.array([
        [11, 12, 13, 14],
        [21, 22, 23, 24],
        [31, 32, 33, 34],
        [41, 42, 43, 44]
    ]),
    kernel_size=(3, 3)
)
)

assert (len(res) == 4)
assert ([x[0].sum() for x in res] == [198, 207, 288, 297])
assert ((res[0][0] == [[11, 12, 13], [21, 22, 23], [31, 32, 33]]).all())
assert ((res[1][0] == [[12, 13, 14], [22, 23, 24], [32, 33, 34]]).all())
assert ((res[2][0] == [[21, 22, 23], [31, 32, 33], [41, 42, 43]]).all())
assert ((res[3][0] == [[22, 23, 24], [32, 33, 34], [42, 43, 44]]).all())
```

Comment: that `convolve_2d` code doesn't actually do any calculations. what is going on?

Comment: That's what I'm wondering too. I tried different options but could not evaluate 'Yield' parameter. If convolve_2d is an python generator then it should activate when I call.

Comment: I'm saying **it does not calculate anything**. look at the code. no calculations. I don't care if you use yield or not. that code is pointless. it serves no purpose. it dumps the input image a ton of times. and your assertions will obviously fail because that function doesn't even **try** to do what it has to do to satisfy those assertions.